# Variable in function returning NaN error

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I'm trying to pass in two parameters into a function. I want to take the parameter "item" and divide it by parameter "sum", than times by 100 and round the number I get. However, the variable "percent" I store the result in says it is NaN. Any ideas on what would be causing this?

```
function calcPercent(item, sum)
    {
        var percent = item / sum;
        percent = percent * 100;
        return Math.round(percent);

    }
```

When debugging the code in my ide, item = Array[3] and sum = 94000

Comment: This happens when one of the operands of `/` is not a number. Please show the callsite of `calcPercent`, or at least print out `item` and `sum` as the first line of `calcPercent` to ensure they're both numbers.

Comment: When debugging the code in my ide, item = Array[3] and sum = 94000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work assuming `item` and `sum` are actually numbers. In fact it will even cast strings to numbers to help you out. It won't work if `item` or `sum` are undefined, or if one are both are some sort of object like an array. You should make sure you know what is being passed into this function. Maybe a quick `console.log(item, sum)` in the function will help figure out what those values are.

Comment: When debugging the code in my ide, item = Array[3] and sum = 94000

Comment: So that's a problem. `item` isn't a number and javascript doesn't know what to do when you try to divide an array by an integer. Is there a particular value in that array that you need to use instead? Maybe you want to find the percent of every value in the array. In that case you could loop through it with `forEach` or `for` and send each value to the function.

Comment: yes, I need to get a percentage for each item in the array, so a for loop might work for me.